# Set global properties in karma

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, karma-runner

How to set some global variable to windows object.
In my case we set some model to windows object through *index.html*.
And in our components we use that model directly. But while running unit tests it doesn't found that object and test fails.
I tried setting the model in spec file as: `window.appConfig={};`
But its throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution for this as:
To set some properties to windows object you need to use the below syntax:

> window['appConfig']={};

Also if you are using this in multiple components then we can set this type of variables in 1 js file and provide that file in karma.js and then it can be accessed in any spec file.

> files:['globleKarmaConstants.js'],